# Split file by number of lines and pattern in awk/perl

Tags: perl, awk

I need to split a file into chunks based on approximate number of lines (e.g. ~4 in the example, but thousands in  reality), whilst each file has to start with a pattern that also occurs many times within each chunk.

A block needs to start with `START` and not end with `START` and be >3 lines long

Input file:

```
START
LINE
LINE
START
LINE 
LINE 
START
LINE 
LINE 
LINE 
START
LINE 
START
LINE
```

Desired output files:

File 1

```
START
LINE
LINE
START
LINE
LINE
```

File 2

```
START
LINE 
LINE 
LINE
```

File 3

```
START
LINE 
START
LINE
```

The problem with the following code is that the 2nd occurrence of `/^START/` is included at the end of file 1, when it should be at the start of file 2. I can't work out how get the file to output when the **next** record is `/^START/`. There is no end pattern that I can use.

```
awk '/^START/{f=1} f{ print $0 > "file_"n ; c++} c>3 && /^START/ { n++; c=1; close("file_"n) }' c=1 n=1 file
```

An awk or perl solution would be much appreciated!

Comment: How is the number of `START`s in each block to be determined?

Comment: A block needs to start with `START` and not end with `START` and be >3 lines long

Comment: You should add that information into the question.

Comment: Does `START` ever appear on two consecutive lines?

Comment: What happens if the first pattern repeats at the end. Does it go into a separate file or gets written in the file that has those patterns already?

Comment: The criteria you have described are fulfilled by just copying the file. It starts with `START` and is longer than three lines. What else is there that you're not telling us?

Comment: @Borodin I understood the requirement to be that each file must be as short as possible, with a minimum length of four lines and beginning with `START`.

Comment: @Borodin please re-read the first sentence of the question and see the desired output files, it is clear

Comment: @pudspop: The first sentence of the question is far from clear. That is why I asked the question. In fact *"... based on approximate number of lines (e.g. ~4 in the example, but thousands in reality)"* means nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the output that you want:

```
awk -v out=1 'NR>1 && ++i>3 && /^START/ {++out; i=0} {print > "file" out}' file
```

When all of the conditions are satisfied, increment `out`, which is part of the output filename.

Output:

```
$ cat file1
 0 START
 1 LINE
 2 LINE
 3 START
 4 LINE 
 5 LINE 
$ cat file2
 6 START
 7 LINE 
 8 LINE 
 9 LINE 
$ cat file3
10 START
11 LINE 
12 START
13 LINE
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly, thank you! `START` should not appear on two consecutive lines by the way, except by error. I'm thinking it wouldn't be problematic for your script though, as it would just put the first `START` after line 3 at the top of the next file, is that right?

Comment: No problem, glad it works. The potential issue would arise if `START` occurred on the fourth and fifth lines (for example change `9 LINE` to `9 START`). This would result in there being `START` at the end of file 2 and at the beginning of file 3.