# Streaming split

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to split the output of a program into smaller files. This is a long-running program that prints its output to stderr and I'd like to capture the logs in a series of smaller files rather than in one gigantic file. So what I have is:

```
program 2>&1 | split -l100 &
```

... but to my dismay I found that the `split` tool doesn't actually write any files out to disk until the input buffer ends.  What I want is a streaming tool that automatically copies its input to the output files in a streaming manner without waiting until the source stream ends, which is unnecessary in my case. I've also tried the `-u` option of the `split` tool but it doesn't seem to work unless you choose the `-n` option but that option doesn't really apply in my case because the number of generated files could be arbitrarily high.  Is there a Unix tool that might let me do this?

Comment: Try using `awk`. It can open a new output file every 100 lines.

Comment: Why not `program 2>&1 | split -l100 - output_ &`

Comment: @Barmar I tried the approach here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712730/split-file-by-number-of-lines-and-pattern-in-awk-perl, but it doesn't have the streaming effect I want. It still only seems to commit the changes to disk after the input stream ends.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That doesn't do anything except change the name of the output file.

Comment: If you add a call to `fflush()` after each print it should commit the changes immediately.

Comment: Or just close() each file when it is done? (In the awk proposal.)

Comment: This deficiency in split was fixed in V8.23 (July 2014) http://git.sv.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commitdiff;h=v8.22-48-g5f9a5b3

Answer (score 0):

Barmar's suggestion to add a call to `fflush()` after every iteration in the awk script worked for me. This was preferable to me to calling `close()` on each file when it's done since that would only flush when each file is full, while I wanted a line-buffered behavior.  I also had to configure the output pipe to be line-buffered, so the command in the end looks like this:

```
stdbuf -oL -eL command 2>&1 | awk -v number=1 '++i>1000 {++number; i=0} {print > "file" number; fflush("file" number)}'
```